# AWS GuardDuty cost too high due to CloudTrail events analyzed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-billing, amazon-guardduty, aws-cost-explorer

In my monthly AWS account bill, GuardDuty shows that it analyzed around **1 million** CloudTrail events in the month but when I downloaded the csv with all the events for the month, the row count is close to **400,000** only.
And this is a repeating pattern across different regions and across many months.

Why is number of events analyzed by GuardDuty so high (in turn leading to higher costs)? Am I missing something?

Comment: It bills in increments of 1mil. https://aws.amazon.com/guardduty/pricing/

Comment: Yes I am aware that costs are calculated (prorated) per million requests. And that would've been fine.. but the bill shows charges as $6 or $4.68 (and so on) based on number of requests (say 1.5million at $0.000004) per request. So it isn't being rounded off.